# Feature boosting via rescaling in logistic regression and linear SVMs

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, svm, feature-selection, binary-data

If I were expressing a problem in terms of binary features, all encoded as {0,1}, could I boost some features by encoding them as {0,2}?  Would the effect change based on whether I used either of the approaches above (logistic regression or linear SVMs?)  Any paper recommendations that would explain the mathematics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No**, those are linear methods, the results would be equivalent. Multiplying $x$ by two would be offset by halfing the coefficient estimate.

Comment: i guess you’d need to tweak the optimization algorithm (e.g.  gradient descent) to favor some of the parameters over others?